# jQuery ajax with autocomplete: bugs in implementing it with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have been trying to implement **jquery-ui autocomplete** in my django project and I used ajax with it but I could not find how to return values from ajax call so instead I wrapped the autocomplete function inside the success function of the ajax it did work for me but there's a bug and it is as follows

```js
$( "#file-search").keyup(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/admins/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { keyword : this.value },
    success: function( data ) {
  var availableTags;
  availableTags = data;
  $(function() {
    $( "#file-search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
  });
      });
    },
 error: function() {}
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The scenario is when the type a character in the input box like (image ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlvVO.png)))

I don't get any suggestions but if I erase it and than type again that same character or any character I get the suggestions just fine like (image ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCaDk.jpg)))
My view is that I'm lacking in the programming logic here or in simple words how to return what and where and which function should go where so please help me out always appreciated.
Big Thanks Already

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: Not certain why pattern at Question being used ? Tried removing `$(function() {})` from around `.autocomplete()` ; or try implementing http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache at "viewsource" ?

Comment: I did try removing $(function () {} ) from around .autocomplete(); and it did not work but I can't understand how to use source: function(request, response) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not triggering a search event after getting the autocomplete data. You can trigger is using the `search` method in your 'success' event handler as follows:

```
success: function(data) {
  $( "#file-search" ).autocomplete({
    source: data
  });

  $( "#file-search" ).autocomplete( "search", this.value );
}
```

The documentation for `search` is [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search).

A few observations:

1. You're asking the server for JSON on EVERY keystroke. You don't want that many round trips to the server in a real environment. I'd suggest building and sending just one gzipped JSON to the client containing completions for all letters of the alphabet. You could defer this action until the user focuses on the search field or something.
2. You're selecting `'#file-search'` twice in your code, thrice if you add my line. You only need to do it once.
3. The first two lines of your success event handler are redundant.
4. I'm not familiar with `jqui`, but it seems like initializing autocomplete on your element on each keystroke isn't a great idea, either. Try to see if you can avoid repeating it.